# On a a plotted graph I will like to know the area with maximum triangular intersection

Tags: matlab

I have the code below to link nine different coordinates in the plotted graph:

```
A1={[1, 1; 1, 5; 3, 9; 4, 2; 4, 6; 6, 2; 7, 6; 6, 9; 9, 9]};
A = cell2mat(A1);
figure
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'oc','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',5);
axis([0 10 0 10]);
xlabel('X-Coordinates')
ylabel('Y-Coordinates')
grid on
hold on
for ii = 1:size(A, 1) - 1
    for jj = ii + 1:size(A, 1)
        line([A(ii, 1), A(jj, 1)], [A(ii, 2), A(jj, 2)])
    end
end
```

The linkages form different triangles. My problem is I will like to know the region with the highest number of triangular intersections.

Can anyone please help with this problem? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should check `boundary` function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: @RCaetano how can the function `boundary` help in this case ?

Comment: As far I understand the question Kola wants to get the largest area created from all triangles. Those triangles result from linking each point to another, so, if `boundary` is used in the inital set of points it could give the area limits.

Comment: Actually, what I looking for is the point with the highest number of triangular intersections, which should be a small area within the triangles. I am not looking for the area created by all the triangles. Still waiting for help. Thanks

Comment: @Kola can you explain what you mean by "triangular intersections".

Comment: The function `polyxpoly`find the intersection points for lines or polygon edges.

Comment: When you run the code, each coordinate will link every other coordinate, forming 84 triangles (9 combination 3). However, I believe that there should be a region with the highest number of triangles overlapping each other (area with most triangles intersecting each other). polyxploy only gives coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below answered my question:

```
A1={[1, 1; 1, 5; 3, 9; 4, 2; 4, 6; 6, 2; 7, 6; 6, 9; 9, 9]};
A = cell2mat(A1);
k = boundary(A);
hold on;
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'oc','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',5);
axis([0 10 0 10]);
xlabel('X-Coordinates')
ylabel('Y-Coordinates')
grid on


for ii = 1:size(A, 1) - 1
    for jj = ii + 1:size(A, 1)
        line([A(ii, 1), A(jj, 1)], [A(ii, 2), A(jj, 2)])
    end
end

% Create the combination of all points that make the triangles
% This could be used to plot the lines as well
N = size(A,1);
comb = [];
for i = 1:N-2
    for j = i+1:N-1
        comb = [comb; repmat([i j], N-j,1) (j+1:N)']; %#ok<AGROW>
    end
end
nComb = size(comb,1);

% Create a mesh grid
dg = 0.01; % Resolution - tune this!
gridEdge = [min(A);max(A)];
[X, Y] = meshgrid(gridEdge(1,1):dg:gridEdge(2,1), gridEdge(1,2):dg:gridEdge(2,2));

% Check if a point is inside each triangle
[isInside, onEdge] = deal(zeros(numel(X),nComb));
for i = 1:nComb
   [isInside(:,i), onEdge(:,i)] = inpolygon(X(:),Y(:),A(comb(i,:),1),A(comb(i,:),2));
end
% Remove points on edge
isInside = isInside - onEdge; 

% Get index of points with most intersection
inTri = sum(isInside,2);
idx = find(inTri == max(inTri));

% Plot result
hold on
plot(X(idx),Y(idx),'.')
text(mean(X(idx)),mean(Y(:)),num2str(max(inTri)),'FontSize',20)
```

A big thank you to nilZ0r.